# Как выводить лист сообщений в чате?

Tags: asp.net

Я пишу чат. Чат организовал с помощью двух фреймов. В одном фрейме отображается лист сообщений. В другом фрейме содержится тексбокс для отправки сообщений в бд. Я не могу разобраться, как правильно выводить лист сообщений чата? Нужно ли использовать определенный элемент управления? Вот, что делал я, но возможно сделал глупо. Я выводил текст в div элемент. Но после каждой отправки сообщения, предыдущее сообщение стирается текущим. Я не могу понять, как сделать чтобы не стирались предыдущие сообщения. Или возможно, мой способ вывода сообщений чата не правильный. Если так, то как сделать нужно? Привожу свой код, того, что у меня получилось. Заранее спасибо за помощь.
Вот разметка с [asp.net](http://asp.net)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="webchat.Messages" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chatMenu" runat="server">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код C#

```
public partial class Messages : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string chatMessage = string.Empty;//временная переменная для хранения сообщения чата
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.ReadFromDataBase();//считываем сообщения из БД чата
        if (message.ReceivedDate != Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.0001 0:00:00") && message.ReceivedMessage != null)//Если строка из БД с сообщением не пустая, выводим сообщение
        {
            chatMessage = string.Empty;
            chatMenu.InnerHtml = string.Format("{0}: {1}", message.ReceivedDate, message.ReceivedMessage);//записываем сообщение в div тег с id chatMenu
            chatMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1} <br />", message.ReceivedDate, message.ReceivedMessage);//записываем сообщение во временную переменное
        }
        else//Иначе выводим текущее сообщение. Если отсутсвует эта строка, после каждого обновления страницы будет выводится пустое сообщение
        {
            chatMenu.InnerHtml = chatMessage;
        }

        message.DeleteMessageFromDb();//Удаляем строку с сообщением
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chatMenu.InnerHtml += string.Format("{0}: {1}<br /> ", message.ReceivedDate, message.ReceivedMessage);
```

Это по поводу стирания сообщений.
Да и, наверно, форму можно убрать, а повесить `ajax`, который будет слать новые сообщение на страницу `.aspx` и выводить их. Надеюсь, как переменный передать в `js` знаешь? Напомню:
`сs`:

```
public string test = "HashCode";
```

`html/js`:

```
<script>
alert('<%=test %>')
</script>
```

Компонентов никаких не надо, просто нужно правильно сверстать, ну и красиво.